# How to put pointer Value from custom table to _User table column?

Tags: android, pointers, object, parse-platform

I am working on android parse.com. I have a custom table "UserInfo" and I want to save my UserInfo ObjectID in _User table `info<pointer>` column. I am using following code to get the value from UserInfo to put Object ID in `info<pointer>` column, but it is not pasting the value.

```
final ParseObject update = new ParseObject("UserInfo");
final ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
user.put("info", ParseObject.createWithoutData("UserInfo",kjh));
```